# SPOJ small factorials problem

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the exact question

> You are asked to calculate factorials of some small positive integers.
>
> *Input:*
>
> An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.
>
> *Output:*
>
> For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of n!
>
> **Example**
>
> *Sample input:*
>
> ```
> 4    
> 1    
> 2    
> 5    
> 3
> ```
>
> *Sample output:*
>
> ```
> 1    
> 2    
> 120    
> 6
> ```

I have coded the SPOJ small factorials problem no 24, but the judge is saying as wrong answer. Please have a look at my code and help me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long numOfTestCases=0;
        string factForAll = "";
        numOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        long[] numArray = new long[numOfTestCases];
        for (long i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
        {
            numArray[i]= Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        }
       
        foreach (var item in numArray)
        {
            long factResult = findFact(item);
            factForAll += factResult+"\n";
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(factForAll);
        
    }
    public static long findFact(long number)
    {
        long factorial = 1;
        if (number<=1)
        {
            factorial = 1;
        }
        for (long i = 1; i <=number; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        return factorial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the question please, or the actual question.

Comment: Because there isn't more information, I would guess it's wrong because it doesn't answer the question right away.  You build a string and print it after all the input is read and you don't tell them how to break out (pressing F6, Enter, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the first comment you need to write each answer on a single line, in c3 that is "\r\n", not "\n".

Answer (score 0):

The problem specifies that the numbers are in the range `1 <= n <= 100`. You are calculating the factorial of these in `long` variables. The range of a `long` is `–9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`. The result will easily overflow this range.

For example,

```
100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

You will need to use something like [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to manipulate numbers this large.

Comment: Thank you.. I figured out and modified the code.. Now its working. But unfortunately the judge's system is not configured to run on the latest framework and hence my solution is treated as wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

C# is not an optimal language choice on SPOJ.com because everything runs on Unix/Linux servers, and the version of C# used is actually Mono 2.. that is why a lot of stuff is not supported, and will not run as expected.

So i would recommend switching to C++ or Java :)